# Javascript: Regex to find string between last occurrence of a string and another string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find the text occurring between the last occurrence of the word "to" in a sentence and another word "Mary".

So, for the sentence

"I went on Friday morning to  bed, then to arrive for that thing and then to beloved Mary"

My regex should match the string "beloved".

I've tried the following code:

```
var str = "I went on Friday morning to  bed, then to arrive for that 
thing and then to beloved Mary";
var r = /to\b(.*)Mary/g
var match = r.exec(str);
console.log(match);
```

And am using the global flag as I want to match all occurrences of the word "to".  I'm expecting it to return an array of strings, with one of them being the string "beloved" but the output I get is:

> ["to  bed, then to arrive for that thing and then to beloved Mary", "  bed, then to arrive for that thing and then to beloved "]

Jsbin here:

http://jsbin.com/puyijo/edit?js,console

Any suggestions?

EDIT: The word "Mary" is not necessarily at the very end of the string.

Comment: Is `Mary` at end of string ?

Comment: Not necessarily - question edited

Comment: [`/.*to\b *(.*?) *\bMary/g`](https://regex101.com/r/w1iTh7/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're looking for the *last* occurrence of `to`, you can greedily consume any other instances of `to` with `.*`:

```
 /.*to\b(.*)Mary/
```

With the requirement you've described, the `/g` is not necessary, since there can only be one "last occurrence of `to`"

Answer (score 0):

You need to match something before the actual to-Mary sequence:

```
var r = /.+to(.+)Mary/
```

You also do not use the group flag.

Then your matching group is the 1st group: `match[1]`.

Note that if you might want to trim the result, or add some other chars outside the group in the regex, e.g. `\s,;\.` to not capture those, if you only want the word/s in between.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Regex parser is greedy by default, so it will first try starting from the first occurrence of `to`.

You need to discard all the previous characters using `.*`:

```
/.*to\b *(.*?) *\bMary/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern `/(to)(?!.*\1)(.*)Mary/g`

1. `'(to)(?!.*\1)'` its matching the last `to`
2. `(.*)` is find the text between `to` and `Mary`

[**Demo Regex**](https://regex101.com/r/8S8Go8/4/)

```js
var str = "I went on Friday morning to  bed, then to arrive for that thing and then to beloved Mary";
var r = /(to)(?!.*\1)(.*)Mary/g;
var match = r.exec(str);
console.log(match[2]);
```